# Failed deserializing XML due to object names mismatch

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, types, model

I tried to deserialize XML object into model and failed due to parsing error.

My code is:

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Status", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class SomeClass
    {

    public DateTime? LastStatusUpdate;

    [XmlElement("LastStatusUpdate")]
    public string LastStatusUpdateString
    {
       set { LastStatusUpdate = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? XmlConvert.ToDateTime(value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Unspecified) : (DateTime?)null; }
    }
    }
```

Since the xmlElement and the DateTime object have the same name, deserialization failed.
When I changed the name of the DateTime param, it worked.

Why?

Comment: The reason for the failure is LastStatusUpdate is declared public.  Make it private and it should work.

Comment: @jdweng while that *will work*, IMO it isn't the best way to solve it, when it can also trivially be fixed without impacting accessibility.

Comment: @Marc Gravell : Absolutely wrong!!!  Did you look at the code?  The OP is converting a custom DataTime string to an object using a "set".  So the property has to be private so the serializer isn't serializing both properties.

Comment: @shlosi : The Xml Serializer seems to always want a GET property and will not work with just a SET from my experience.  I've tried last week with just a SET and it didn't work.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the insult, I'm clearly ignorant of everything serialization related... I must have imagined `[XmlIgnore]`...

Comment: @jdweng re set-only; this actually depends on the framework - the internals were completely changed for .NET Core, and it has different rules and behavior to .NET Framework on that topic (or that may be when having an accessor that exists, but where the accessor is non-public on a public member - specifically (just checked), they fail at different times - netfx throws when generating a serializer instance; netcoreapp generates a serializer, and throws when it is used)

Comment: The OP said "Since the xmlElement and the DateTime object have the same name, deserialization failed".  Making private will fix this issue no matter what version of Net.

Comment: Thanks guys for this educating debate.
I will change it now to private (feeling ignorant for not noticing that before).
However, even though there is no GET property, it works just fine.
I guess XML class has a default GET for it's properties?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `[XmlIgnore]` to `LastStatusUpdate`, so it knows not to look at it. Then the *other one* (`LastStatusUpdateString` with `[XmlElement("LastStatusUpdate")]`) should work without problem.

By default, `XmlSerializer` works as though every public member `Foo` had `[XmlElement]` on it, which treats it as an element of the same name as the member (so: `<Foo>`).

It also seems odd that you don't have a `get` on `LastStatusUpdate` - it very much feels like there should be a:

```cs
get => LastStatusUpdate == null ? null :
    XmlConvert.ToString(LastStatusUpdate.Value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Unspecified);
```

and

```cs
public bool ShouldSerializeLastStatusUpdateString() => LastStatusUpdate.HasValue;
```